# why the two variables not getting the new value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to assign a value to the two starting variables in the following code, and change them if necessary (first if and elif), but the smallest gets changed to the string "done" while the largest stays untouched. what am I missing ?

Thank you very much

```
largest = 0
smallest = 999
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if largest > num:
        largest = num
    elif smallest < num: 
        smallest = num
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input"
    if num == "done" : break


print "Maximum is", largest 
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Edited the code as per suggestions as follow:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

try:
    num = int(num)
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    elif smallest < num: 
            smallest = num

except ValueError:
    print "Invalid input"
if num == "done" : break


print "Maximum is", largest 
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Now it runs correctly

Comment: you need to convert num to an integer. Also, why is largest=0 and smallest=999?

Comment: You probably meant to do `if num > largest :`

Comment: because when they originally were set to None, it wouldn't update so I tried with a starting value

Comment: Thank you @Shalan & Joel

Comment: I have a question: Where the var "num" is set to "done" ? I don't understand. I tested your code and it loop again and again with the prompt input asking to "Enter a number".

Comment: @AdrienLeber it is supposed to loop forever up until the user input is "done", after that the program breaks the otherwise infinite loop. Just to clarify , the var num is not set to the sting done, that would be    num = "done". instead is a IF statement that checks if the input from the user is the string "done", and if so it stops the program

Comment: @Schwarz, Thank for explaination. Got it. ; )